# PyQt5 dynamically update a contents of a QGridLayout

Tags: python-3.x, linux, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to implement a way to display widgets in a QGridLayout dynamically, based on contents of a folder. The purpose is being able to save configuration in .ini files and then have them displayed as widgets in a grid. So far it works, but only updates the QGridLayout contents to show the newly saved .ini only after I restart the program. I have only managed to delete the previous contents when I create a new entry, but the QGridLayout doesn't seem to get repopulated.

Long story short, I want to save a new configuration as a .ini file and dynamically have it added to the QGridLayout with the previously saved files.

This is the code I wrote to set up the presets page in a QStackedWidget page (the stretching is way off as I'm still trying to make that work properly with an arbitrary number of widgets as well, but I doubt that's relevant to the issue):

```
    def readPresets(self):
        directory = os.fsencode("presets/")
        presetList = []
        for file in os.listdir(directory):
            filename = os.fsdecode(file)
            if filename.endswith(".ini"):
                print(filename.split('.', 1)[0])
                presetList.append(filename)#.split('.', 1)[0])
            else:
                print("No presets found")
        return sorted(presetList)

    def setupPresetsPage(self):
        col = 1
        row = 1
        presetList = self.readPresets()
        pColor = ConfigRead("PrimaryColor")
        sColor = ConfigRead("SecondaryColor")

        self.presetsGrid.setColumnStretch(0,3)
        if len(presetList) < 4:
            self.presetsGrid.setColumnStretch(len(presetList)+1,3)
        else:
            self.presetsGrid.setColumnStretch(5,3)
        self.presetsGrid.setRowStretch(0,4)

        for i, preset in enumerate(presetList):

            self.presetsGrid.setColumnStretch(col, 2)
            self.presetsGrid.setRowStretch(row, 3)
            self.presetsGrid.addWidget(Preset(pValues[0],pValues[1],pValues[2],
                                            sValues[0], sValues[1],sValues[2]),
                                            row ,col)

            if col == 4:
                col = 1
                row += 1
            else:
                col += 1
            if i == len(presetList):
                self.presetsGrid.setRowStretch(row, 4)

        self.presetsPage = Page("Presets", self.presetsGrid)
```

This is how I'm clearing the layout:

```
  def clearPresets(self):
        if self.presetsGrid.count() != 0:
            for i in range(self.presetsGrid.count()):
                self.presetsGrid.itemAt(i).widget().deleteLater()
```

I had assumed that if I cleared the layout and then called setup again, it should work as intended. I'm hoping someone can give some feedback on this.

EDIT: It kind of works now, but the first time I save a preset it doesn't add it to the grid, then the next time I save one it adds the previously saved one and so on. It is basically one widget behind to display
EDIT: The method I use for saving:

```
def save(obj, settings):
    for widget in obj.findChildren(QWidget):
        if isinstance(widget, QSlider):
            name = widget.objectName()
            parent = widget.parent().objectName()
            value = widget.value()
            settings.setValue(parent+"/"+name, value)
        if isinstance(widget, CycleBox):
            name = widget.objectName()
            parent = widget.parent().objectName()
            index = widget.optionStack.currentIndex()
            settings.setValue(parent+"/"+name, index)
```

```
    def savePreset(self):
        counter = 0
        presetName = "presets/myPreset{}.ini"
        while os.path.isfile(presetName.format(counter)):
            counter+=1
        presetName = presetName.format(counter)
        settings = QtCore.QSettings(presetName, QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
        SaveConfig.save(self.parent(), settings)
        self.setupPresetsPage()
```

Some output that may help (presetsList contents is what also gets displayed in GUI):

```
clear
0
setup
read
['myPreset0.ini']  #presets/ folder contents on startup, folder actually 
                   #has a single file
grid widget count: 1
save
clear
0
setup
read
['myPreset0.ini']  #presets/ folder contents after first save, but folder now 
                   #actually has two files
grid widget count: 1
save
clear
0
setup
read
['myPreset1.ini', 'myPreset0.ini'] #after third time I save, folder has
                                   #3 files.
grid widget count: 2
```

Comment: The code you give is not enough to fully understand what you are doing. For example, its not clear how you are saving the settings. You should provide a [minimal reproduciple example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The saving is just done using QSettings as .ini files. Going through widgets and saving their states.

Comment: I have updated the question. I am only trying to save widget states in myPresetX.ini files while displaying them as squares in a grid. I want every time i'm saving a new myPresetX.ini to add a new square for it to that grid right away, but I have to save again in order to show the previously saved entry and so on. Calling the savePreset() method from one button and then the readPresets() and setupPresetsPage() from another one works, but not if I call the latter from savePresets() so I only have to click one button. presetList gets updated one entry behind.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]